# What's the best way to remove duplicates from a string in PHP (or any language)?

Tags: php, deduplication

I am looking for the best known algorithm for removing duplicates from a string.  I can think of numerous ways of doing this, but I am looking for a solution that is known for being particularly efficient.

Let's say you have the following strings:

- `Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum`
- `Lorem Lorem Lorem`
- `Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor Lorem Ipsum Dolor`

I would expect this algorithm to output for each (respectively):

- `Lorem Ipsum`
- `Lorem`
- `Lorem Ipsum Dolor`

Note, I am doing this in PHP, in case anybody is aware of any built in PHP functions that can help with this.

Thanks!

Comment: What if you had "Lorem Ipsum Ipsum Dolor Ipsum"? Would you want the output to be "Lorem Ipsum Dolor"?

Comment: Nope, not removing duplicate words, just duplicate patterns of words

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$arr = explode( " " , $string );
$arr = array_unique( $arr );
$string = implode(" " , $arr);
```

Comment: Thanks, the answer is actually very elegant.

Comment: would be like  `implode(" ",array_unique(explode(" ", $string )))` in  signle line ;)

Answer (score 2):

Dunno about efficiency, but maybe this can do:

```
$str = implode(" ", array_unique(explode(" ", $str)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$words = array_unique(explode(' ',$text));
echo implode(' ',$words);
```

if you want to make it better you can use preg_split with \s\W for exploding words

Answer (score 1):

Best way of doing it:

1. Sort the words inside string
2. Remove duplicates by iterating the sorted words

Other possibility is using a `set` construction if your language supports it.

Comment: This is a good answer, but requires the extra step of putting the string back into it's original order.

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code for removing duplicate code from any sentence

```
$arr = explode(" " , $string);
$arr = preg_replace('/(\w{2,})(?=.*?\\1)\W*/', '', $arr);
$string = implode(" " , $arr);
```